# How do you solve a system of equations in the form $x+y=3, xy=4$?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, factoring

I am trying to factor this polynomial:
$x^2+3x+4$.
and couldn't think of any integer solution (I don't think there is a real solution either) so I created this system of equations.
$x+y=3$ and $xy=4$.
The only problem is, I have no idea how to solve a system of this form. Please use terms that an Algebra 1 student would understand.

Comment: The quadratic has no real solutions since its discriminant is $b^2-4ac=3^2-4(1)(4)=-7<0$.

Comment: In regards to the source of the question, when trying to factor a quadratic polynomial, one may use the *quadratic formula*: $ax^2+bx+c=(x-\frac{-b+ \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})(x-\frac{-b- \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})$.  Although factoring by inspection can often be quicker and more satisfying, if you run into a roadblock like this there is no reason be stuck.

Comment: Since $b^{2}-4ac=3^{2}-4.1.4<0$, there is no real solution as you think.

Comment: You can also prove this by completing the square: $$x^2+3x+4=x^2+3x+\frac94-\frac94+4=\left(x+\frac32\right)^2+\frac74$$ and since each term is positive the expression can never equal $0$.

Comment: Normally, it works the other way: solving system $x+y=s$, $xy=p$ comes down to solving the quadratic equation $t^2-st+p=0$! Incidentally, it's $x+y=\color{red}-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s$ be the sum and $p$ the product.

Then write $x=\dfrac s2+z$ and $y=\dfrac s2-z$, so that $x+y=s$, and from $xy=p=\dfrac{s^2}4-z^2$ you can draw $z$.